# How do I get my LaTeX font for the usage in other software

Tags: fonts

I am using my university default LaTeX file for my thesis (written in LaTeX). I am still not sure how the font that LaTeX uses is called, but if I click in `font --> properties` it appears with the name of *CM R 12*. Is it equivalent to a common font name that typically MS Word would use?

I am wondering how I could use that same font in my other software, such as MS Word, Adobe Photoshop, etc.?  How should I install it on my mac?

I am using MacBook Pro, with OS 10.9.1.

Comment: `CM R` stands for Computer Modern Roman, which is the default LaTeX font. It is available for download online, since it is open-source. Beyond that, your question belongs on another website.

Comment: http://www.gust.org.pl/projects/e-foundry/latin-modern/download